# How to get string from multiple json array inside a json object

Tags: android, json

{
"data:"
 {
    "calendar":
              [
                {
                      "Booked":["13-11-2015","12-12-2015"],
                      "Available":["20-12-2015","22-12-2015"]
                }
              ]
 }
}

Could any one please help me how to get date from json array string

Comment: This is a invalid json array

Answer (score 2):

Your json should be like this

```
{
  "data": {
    "calendar": [
      {
        "Booked": [
          "13-11-2015",
          "12-12-2015"
        ],
        "Available": [
          "20-12-2015",
          "22-12-2015"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can use [json online parser](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to check the validity of a json.

Now, coming back to your actual question.I dont have an android IDE so I will post a quick code to give u an idea

```
JSONObject jparentobj= new JSONObect("jsonString");

JSONObject datajObj= jparentobj.getJSONObect("data");

JSONArray calenderarray = datajObj.getJSONArray{"calender");

for (int i = 0; i < calenderarray.size(0); i++){
String booked = calenderarray.get(i).getString("Booked");
//Like this get each entity

}
```

Hope this helps you..