# how to retrieve multiple JSONArray object in one JSONObject using android

Tags: android, arrays, json

Any one please get Strings in  multiple JSONArray object using one JSONObject in android. Thank You.

```
"marks": {
    "Language 1 English": {
        "Theory": ["ASL", "", "", "", ""],
        "ASL": ["ASL", "", "", "", ""]
    },
    "Mathematics": {
        "Theory": ["", "100", "33", "0", "Failed"]
    },
    "Physics": {
        "Theory": ["Practical", "80", "27", "94", "Passed"],
        "Practical": ["Practical", "", "", "", ""]
    },
    "Chemistry": {
        "Theory": ["Practical", "", "", "", ""],
        "Practical": ["Practical", "", "", "", ""]
    },
    "Biology/ Computer Science": {
        "Theory": ["Practical", "100", "33", "30", "Failed"],
        "Practical": ["Practical", "", "", "", ""]
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly is a problem for you to get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse JSON Array without Key in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586069/parse-json-array-without-key-in-android)

Comment: Can't retrieve Pratical json array .

Comment: You take help from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33819700/how-to-get-string-from-multiple-json-array-inside-a-json-object

Comment: `Can't retrieve Pratical json array` show what you have tried

Comment: 'JSONArray Pratical_array = MARKS_array.getJSONArray("Practical");
                           for (int g = 0; g < Pratical_array.length(); g++) {                                  String Pratical_marks = Pratical_array.get(g).toString();'

Comment: and what is the problem? As I can see `marks` object doesn't have a JSONArray called `Practical` in it.